# Multiple levels of authorization, not only role-based

Tags: authorization, acl

Our application uses multiple ways for authorizing access to a given resource. Although it's working, it's messy and... well, it doesn't seem right.

#### 1) Role-based authorization

We have well defined roles where each role has access to a set of the resources and different roles can access the same resources.

Resources, as of now, are simply MVC actions mapped in a database table as `module`, `controller` and `action`.

This seems to be OK, but every time I need to add a new controller/action I have to map this resource to the database table.

#### 2) User-based authorization

Besides role-based authorization, users can have more or less access to a subset of resources of another role. **Eg.:**

**RoleA**: resources *a*, *b*, *c*, *d*
**RoleB**: resources *x*, *y*, *z*
**RoleC**: resources *1*, *2*, *3*
**User1**: has **RoleA** but needs to access resource *y*
**User2**: has **RoleB** and **RoleC** but does not have access to resource *z*

This is implemented as an `user_resources` table with entries for additional resources that the user has access or is denied (indicated by a flag).

I could create different roles with tailored access, treating roles as group of permissions, but that would lead to a roles explosion.

#### 3) Model state authorization

If that's not enough, some actions can only be performed when the model is in a certain state (each model knows when something can be done). **Eg.:** an order can only be edited if the user has access to the *edit* resource (through steps #1 or #2) and the object `Order` can be edited.

**Anoter example:** an user can access a `Customer` if he has access to `/customer/view` resource and he *owns* that Customer (he is the contact info for that customer).

#### 4) Display information in UI

A role, group of roles or individual users can see more or less information about a model, depending on it's state.

How can I simplify this authorization process without loosing flexibility in giving or restraining access to resources?

There is any pattern I'm missing here to unify all this authorization in a single place?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After a long time I finally found an answer that satisfies all my requirements:
http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/05/24/dont-do-role-based-authorization-checks-do-activity-based-checks/.

His solution is to consider everything as an activity, the permission to execute/call/whatever an activity is given to a role and users can have multiple roles.

What shines in this approach is that the permission check is done on the activity itself, not on the roles.

Comment: This approach doesn't handle the "model state authorization" you mention though. How do you handle the case you mention - a user can see a customer if he has access to "VIEW_CUSTOMER AND owns that customer?

Comment: I implemented the authorization service using the Specification pattern. For example a `CancelOrder` activity have 2 specifications: `CloseOrderSpecification` (for basic authorization check) and `CloseOwnOrdersSpecification` for model state authorization. If these 2 specifications are satisfied, the user has access to the activity.

Comment: What I most liked about the blog post was the ability to really separate concerns - e.g. if you annotate your method with an activity tag SOME_ACTIVITY, you can separate the checks elsewhere.
In your approach using the Specification pattern, where do you code your Specifications? Do you perform the checks on the body of the activity (simple, but need re-coding when it changes) or elsewhere (cleaner, but probably harder to access all the model objects needed)?

Answer (score 10):

I've implemented access control by using the [specification pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern), which I find directly suited for this. A central method is `isSatisfiedBy`. X is allowed to do y if it is satisfied by z. Eg a user is allowed to view 'the admin page' if it is satisfied by 'has admin role'. See how `isSatisfiedBy` can be very generic (eg 'is user with id 324', 'has been logged in for 30 minutes', 'is member of group foo', ...). Rules then become of the following general form:

```
allow X to do Y if X satisfies Z
```